# Custom Dialog with listview and listitems having different background at alternate items?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-dialog, customdialog

I am creating a custom dialog having two images as a title and a listview inside the dialog.
in that listview there is some items i am showing and now i want that the items in the listview should get different background?
like suppose i have 5 items to show in a list view then the items in position 1,3,5 are having different background than items at position 2,4.
is it possible? help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom adapter when loading items in your listview.

Create a layout xml for an item in the listview and set it.

Like myitemlist_row.xml and in the activity :

```
MyAdapter _adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.myitemlist_row, null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER, this);
_mylist.setAdpater(_adapter);
```

Sample code for the adapter :

```
@Override 
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
{ 
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor); 

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag(); 

    if (holder == null) 
    { 
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.Background_Layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Background_Layout);
    }

    //you can use now holder.Background_Layout.setBackgroundColor or setBackgroundDrawable accordind to the data, as you want
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming you're using a adapter...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<item_layout>, null);

    }
    else
    if(pos%2==0)
         vi.setBackgroundResource(<image_1_res_id>);
    else
         vi.setBackgroundResource(<image_2_res_id>);
    return vi;
}
```